# Word wrapping is broken on the election page

Tags: bug, status-completed, election

Some, but not all, of the paragraphs on [the election page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) have broken word wrapping. Here's a screenshot of what I see for lyxal's answers to questions 5 and 6:

[image]

The question 5 paragraph is wrapping a bunch of lines mid-word, leaving only one letter at the beginning or end of the line, for no apparent reason. The question 6 paragraph is completely normal. If it matters, I'm on Firefox 105 on Kubuntu 22.04, with a 1920x1080 screen resolution and 100% scaling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fixed now, thanks to Catija. See [Prevent nonbreaking spaces from making an election completely non-responsive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382528/323179). It is apparently a bad idea to use nonbreaking spaces in a nomination, especially in the election phase.